# What Dark side organizations exist in Star Wars universe, apart from The Sith?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The Sith are clearly the most prominent and well-known dark-side user group, but from both the EU and canon stories, what would be other powerful Dark Jedi organizations or groups?

I want to know as I'm writing a fanfic that involves the Jedi having to deal with both the Sith and another dark-side organization that proves to be very powerful.

Comment: Would a dark side organization that isn't specifically "Dark Jedi" count? I'm thinkig the Nightsisters.

Comment: I know of them but I'm thinking of more of a lightsaber-wielding type of Dark Jedi.

Answer (score 9):

The [Rakatan Infinite Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Empire) was an immensely powerful dark side organization that was actually the origin of lightsabers in Legends. They were destroyed around the time that "Sith" started to exist (though they weren't called that at the time), so they probably aren't helpful for your story unless you want it to take place long before the Old Republic.

Answer (score 5):

## Depending on the era:

- Before and during the Clone Wars - [The Nightsisters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nightsisters) (not exactly lightsaber-wielders, but dark side users they were).
- Rise of the Empire - [The Inquisitorius](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitorius) mentioned in another answer
- After Empire (canon) - [The Knights of Ren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren) (cannot be #2 by then, as the Sith were extinct).
- (Any period) - individual dark side adepts (Maul after his duel with Obi-Wan, Asajj Ventress, Savage Oppress, etc)

[This wiki link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Dark_side_organizations) may be a starting point to group this info together. Includes a mix of both canon and legends, some info is not up to date, but may still be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The second most powerful Dark Side group, I think, is [The Inquisitorius](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitorius). They serve and help the Sith.
And their leader was Darth Vader.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Your answer would be improved by links to sources, and proofreading. A look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to writing good answers may be helpful.